# LHT00SU1 logic analyzer clock generator

Tags: clock, function-generator, logic-analyzer, signal-generator

I was using a LHT00SU1 logic analyzer and according to [this](https://wiki.geekworm.com/LHT00SU1_Virtual_Oscilloscope_SKU:412961) it should have the capability to produce a variable frequency signal (i assume through the CLK pin).

Using pulseview with fx2lafw firmware I didn't find any way to use that function, is it possible to use it?

Comment: I wouold like to answer your question but when looking up LHT00SU1 I found several non compatible definitions of what it does and how it works. Post a link to the unit you have and also a link to the instructions that you have read.

Comment: I don't have any specific reference, but should be [that one](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Noname_LHT00SU1). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you can do what you want. However I do not have the time to read the manual for you but here is a link to it. https://www.usbee.com/axmanual.pdf I got this information from the link you provided.

The first five lines from your link:

The Noname LHT00SU1 is a USB-based, 8-channel logic analyzer with up to 24MHz sampling rate, with 1 additional analog channel (theoretically 2, but only one of them can be used at a time; 3MHz analog bandwidth).

It is a clone of the CWAV USBee AX-Pro.

In sigrok, we use the open-source fx2lafw firmware for this logic analyzer.

Note: fx2lafw currently doesn't support switching between the two possible analog channels, 1ACH will be used unconditionally.

See Noname LHT00SU1/Info for some more details (such as lsusb -v output) on the device.